# How to use 'compare' for all series except one

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible to draw with Highstock a chart with panels like in this example (http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/candlestick-and-volume) but with possibility to draw in First Panel, multiple Series with Compare option (http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/compare) ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's possible with option compare inside series.

For example:

series = {
  data: data,
  compare: 'percent' 
}
Link to API specs --> http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.compare

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible with option compare inside series. For example: series = { data: data, compare: 'percent' } Link to API specs --> api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.compare

Answer (score 0):

You can use multi line series, but second panel should be pin to yAxis:1

http://jsfiddle.net/SKKSY/

```
  series: [{
            type: 'line',
            name: 'AAPL',
            data: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
        },{
            type: 'line',
            name: 'AAPL',
            data: [11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
        },{
            type: 'line',
            name: 'AAPL',
            data: [21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30]
        }, {
            type: 'column',
            name: 'Volume',
            data: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
            yAxis: 1
        }]
```